# Gremlin query to get locations within 100 mile radius

Tags: geocoding, gremlin

In my data, I have few cities as vertices along with their coordinates as properties.
My goal is, supposing given a center point, i.e, New York City, I want to find out the vertices(cities) which are within a 100-mile radius to NYC so that I can graphically represent the cities along with its associated employees in a 100-mile radius.

I am aware of great circle distance, but it simply calculates the spherical distance between two places.

Comment: Which graph database engine are you using? Some have geospatial predicates and other capabilities built in. In other case you can still come up with some reasonable approximations using the `math` step.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Im using AWS Neptune. I referred to great circle distance from your book!

Comment: I added an initial answer with a few thoughts below

Comment: Thankyou @KelvinLawrence, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

While some graph databases that support Apache TinkerPop have added custom support for geospatial calculations, that capability has not yet been added to Gremlin as a set of predicates and datatypes. That said, it is definitely a topic that is on the radar of the Apache TinkerPop community for a future release.

In the meantime you have a few options.

1. Purely in Gremlin use lat/lon properties to roughly estimate the values you need. The easiest way to do that is to use the bounding box of the circle whose radius you are interested in and then prune out the unwanted ones in your application code. One degree of longitude is roughly 56.4 miles and one degree of latitude is roughly 69 miles (but keep in mind the Earth is spherical and this value varies as you approach the poles.).
2. Write a query that does everything option one needs to do but then use the Haversine Gremlin query to figure out which ones to keep.
3. Store the coordinates using geohashes rather than lat/lon and either do some calculations in Gremlin or your application to find the ones you are interested in.